# Style not applying to line with <hr> element in HTML

Tags: css, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my web page</title>
    <meta name="author" content="akhil">
    <style>
      h1{color: red;font-size: 400%}
      p{color: red}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <h1>hello how are you?</h1>
      <p>i am fine.<hr> what about you?</p>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this document style is applying to `h1` and `p` but it is not applying to line after `hr` tag, how to make style apply to line after `hr` tag?

Comment: And HTML is not a program!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A paragraph cannot contain a `<hr />` tag, so all text after `<hr />` will be out of `<p>` tag. It's better to use this way:

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 400%;
}
p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>hello how are you?</h1>
  <p>i am fine.</p>
  <hr />
  <p>what about you?</p>
</section>
```

This is how the browsers render your code:

[image]

Your content isn't inside the `<p />` tag anymore.

Comment: but still what about you is not coloured,how to make what about you line coloured?

Comment: @AkhilSharma I can see it is red in colour.

Comment: <p>i am fine.</p>
      <hr /><p>what about you?</p> this is what i tried and now it is in colour<thanks praveen

Comment: i have another query ,why you written <hr /> and not simple <hr>?

Comment: @AkhilSharma `<hr />` is a self-closing tag. Personal preference, I use XHTML. `:)` You can use anything.

Comment: ok sorry i did not knew about tick,and what is this xhtml,?can you explain in a more simplified way,i have just strted learning so sorry asking dumb ques.?

Comment: @AkhilSharma XHTML is a strict subset of HTML where you want all the tags to be closed. See [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) and [Comparison](http://www.webstandards.org/learn/articles/askw3c/oct2003/).

Comment: @AkhilSharma I understand... Don't feel shy or dumb to ask questions like that in comments. `:)`

Comment: so if io use <hr /> <br /> <wbr /> ,do old browsers will support it rather <hr>?

Comment: @AkhilSharma Yes. Any browser that support XHTML will support. I don't think you wanna try this on IE3???

Comment: how can i follow you?

Comment: @AkhilSharma Excuse me?

Comment: i mean like ,i am new in this field and you seem like a experienced person,so if sometime need guidance,how can i ask you?

Comment: @AkhilSharma Everyone has a profile page right? You can find my contact information there. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

you can close and open the paragraf:

```
<p>i am fine.</p> <hr><p> what about you?</p>
```